# splitting a string and entering each value into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, explode

I have tags in the form of `tag1,tag2,tag3` that I want to enter into the a table i.e

```
tag_id    tag_name    topic_id
  1         php          1
  2         ajax         2
  3         mysql        3
  4         html         4
```

The script below doesn't do that. I dont get any error on the screen

```
$topic_tag = explode("," , $topic_tags) ;

       foreach($topic_tag as $topic_tags) {
       $query = "INSERT INTO `forum_tags` (`tag_id`, `tag_name`) 
       VALUES ( NULL, '" .mysql_real_escape_string(trim($topic_tags))."')";
       }
```

Comment: Are you executing the query anywhere? You're assigning it to the variable, but I don't see a `$mysqli->query($query);` type call anywhere ...

Comment: And what about topic_id?  Is defined as not null?  Where do you plan to set this value?

Comment: Argh, stop reusing $topic_tag and $topic_tags! And counter-intuitively  no less...

Answer (score 2):

Consider using PDO for your SQL requests :
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

For example :

```
$statement = $pdo_object->prepare('INSERT INTO `forum_tags` (`tag_id`, `tag_name`, `topic_id` ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?) ');
$statement->execute( $topic_tags );
```